# How can I access an attribute of a sibling directive inside of a form using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a counter-for directive that would show the amount of characters entered into an arbitrary input.text or textarea inside of the same form in this format `{{currentCharCount}}/{{maxCharCount}}`

This directive might be used like this:

```
<form name="form">
  <textarea name="username"></textarea>
  <div counter-for="username"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GZ7HWx3ldaUbhZiLysEG?p=preview)

**My approach is to create a directive on the `textarea` element itself:**

```
<form name="form">
   <textarea name="username"
             ng-model="text" 
             ng-max-length="200"
             counter>

   </textarea>
</form>
```

**Inside the directive require `ngModel` and use it's controller:**

```
app.directive('counter', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs,ctrl){
      var max = attrs.ngMaxLength;
      var div = angular.element("<div>0/" + max + "</div>");
      elm.after(div);
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
        var count = (value || '').length + "/" + attrs.ngMaxLength;
        div.html(count);
        return value;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

#### Considerations

- It's better to avoid populating the scope (with extra $watchers) as much as possible.
- There are hacky ways of getting a sibling scope but that's bad design and error prone.
- No scope wants another scope to invade it's territory, and no scope is expecting that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put ng-model in my question. I can get the value that is entered into the textarea. But how can I get the attribute from the textarea? I don't suppose the ng-maxlength attribute is reflected in the scope of the form?

Comment: Yeah I had been hoping to avoid a solution that requires me to put any extra stuff on the element to be counted. An additional attribute to set the ng-max-length into the scope when linked.

Comment: You can also wrap the `textarea` and **transclude it** so you'll get access to it inside your directive. Sibling directives are just strangers to each other, any hack of communicating between them is just another layer of complexity, you don't do that unless you must.